# Update database in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i have in asp.net a few textboxes and i wish to update my database with the values that they encapsulate .

The problem is that it doesn't work and although it doesn't work, the syntax seems correct and there are no errors present . Here is my linkbutton :

```
<asp:linkbutton id="clickOnSave" runat="server" 
                onclick="Save_Click" Text="Save Profile" />
```

and my update function

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\alex\\Documents\\seeubook_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

    con.Open();

    String commandString = "UPDATE users SET last_name='" + Text4.Text.Trim() + "' , first_name='" + Textbox1.Text.Trim() + "' , about_me='" + Textbox5.Text.Trim() + "' , where_i_live='" +  Textbox2.Text.Trim() + "' ,  where_i_was_born='" + Textbox3.Text.Trim() + "' , work_place='" + Textbox4.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE email='" + Session["user"] + "'";

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to format code - 4 spaces, not a `>`.

Comment: i was just formatting the text , sorry

Comment: If you have free time I suggest looking into LINQ to SQL. It is a huge improvement over ADO.NET.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend validating the user input, or at least look into SQL Injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm always a bit weary about the `User Instance=true` in a connection string..... at times, it tends to create a new MDF file "on the fly" and when you update that MDF, then your changes might be just "gone" one your app has completed running.... See [MSDN docs on User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx).

I would suggest that you:

- attach your MDF file to SQL Server Express on your machine, using SQL Server Express Management Studio
- then use a **server-based** approach to your SQL Server Express database rather than attaching a file...

In that case, your database connection string would then look something like:

```
server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

And while you're at it, I would also recommend to:

- wrap your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` blocks to ensure proper disposal
- open your connection as late as possible
- use a **parametrized** query instead of concatenating together your SQL command - doing so is a wide open door for SQL injection attacks!

So your code would look something like this:

```
string connStr = "server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

string cmdStmt = "UPDATE dbo.Users SET last_name = @lastName, " + 
   "first_name = @firstName, about_me = @aboutMe, where_i_live = @whereILive, " +  
   "where_i_was_born = @whereIWasBorn, work_place = @workPlace " +
   "WHERE email = @userEMail";

using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStmt, sqlCon))
{
   // define parameters 
   sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
   sqlCmd.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = Text4.Text.Trim();
   // and so on for all the parameters

   sqlCon.Open();
   sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. The thing is that when i put the update code in the "page_load" function it works, but when i put it in my save function it doesn't work. I've verified that i enter the save function and that the .ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1 so i don't understand why it won't work

Comment: ok marc, i'll send you via email the project + mdf . Thank you a lot for the extra effort !

Answer (score 0):

Debug! Look your LinkButton Click Event really go into Save_Click function. And then check 'sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();' return result.

Comment: it does go into the function and  the function returns "1" . But the changes don't occur

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code for filling Textbox's at page load as below :

```
public page_load()
{
   if(!ispostBack)
   {
     // Write code to fill controls first time
    }
```

}